# Pulseaudio and `shell-command` calls in Emacs

Tags: shell-command, linux

I'm trying to execute shell-commands in emacs which play sounds or otherwise involve audio output, but I'm not having much luck.

When I execute:

```
(shell-command
 (concat "espeak -v mb-en1 -k5 -s150 " "'" "hello" " " "world" "'" " --stdout|paplay"))
```

No audio output is generated and I find the following message:

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
1 (#o1, #x1, ?\C-a)
```

A different though related problem, if I try:

```
(shell-command
                (concat "mplayer -really-quiet " "/usr/share/sounds/speech-dispatcher/test.wav" " 2> /dev/null"))
```

Again, I don't actually get any audio output and I find the message:

```
(Shell command succeeded with no output)
0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)
```

Both commands work as expected from the actual terminal shell (i.e. they produce audio output).

Edit: Ok, this seems to be part of a more general problem.  On my home computer I finally got everything to work by allowing greater permissions to pulse-audio. However, now on my office computer, I'm having trouble getting `notify-send` to work when issued in `shell-command` in Emacs.  I'm getting the same odd `0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)` message when I try to do this.

Comment: How was your Emacs process launched? Was it from a menu in your desktop environment? If so, try running Emacs from a terminal and see if it works. It might be a problem related to the environment being richer in an actual terminal shell.

Comment: Also, try removing `2>/dev/null` from your mplayer command, so that you can see whether there are errors.

Comment: @Francesco: Thanks. Emacs was run as a daemon, autostarting as a process by `systemd`, and running as a process owned by my username. I then launched an `emacsclient` instance. The errors from mplayer had to do with connecting to ALSA.

Comment: Don't use the global `systemd` to start a local Emacs session.  Your process will naturally lack permissions to access local desktop services.  Instead, start it through your Desktop environment, e.g. as KDE autostart job or whatever.

Comment: No, it's not a global `systemd` - but rather as a user unit - as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/emacs#As_a_systemd_unit   -- do you think that that method is still probably a bad idea?

Comment: Since this question is about your operating system and only peripherally about Emacs, [unix.se] would be a better place for it. Do not repost there unless your question is closed here; you can flag your question to request that moderators migrate your question.

Comment: What distribution are you running? What else can you tell us about your environment: apparently you're using systemd, which desktop environment do you use? Have you set up SELinux or other hardening mechanism? How do you start Emacs: from your GUI session, or do you start a daemon first?

Comment: @Gilles - Thanks. I realise at this point that the question is less about Emacs and more about the OS, but that wasn't immediately apparent to me at the outset.  I'm running Arch linux, with no desktop environment, using Awesome as a windows manager. I am using systemd (part of Arch defaults). I haven't set up SELinux or other hardening mechanisms.  I've been having systemd start an Emacs daemon as a user unit as described above - this has seemed to behave like a daemon started from the commandline (e.g. it knows user-specific PATHs etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Running `paprefs` and checking the box next to "enable network access to local sound devices" and under that also the "don't require authentication" box worked as a workaround for the problem.

Comment: You are aware that this enables **any system** in your local network to play sound on your speakers?

Comment: Do you have suggestions on a more limited way of granting permissions such that I can actually get audio output via shell-commands from Emacs?

Comment: Though, actually, now I'm having trouble with `notify-send` (see above edit).

Comment: Start Emacs through your desktop environment, so that it gets proper permissions to access PulseAudio and your DBus session bus (for `notify-send`).